# Not able to access Table Valued Parameter for queries in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters, table-variable

I have two queries in the single stored procedure.
I have one table table valued parameter & that TVP I am using for both the queries.
One of my query is working fine (Update Query is working fine) but If I am using that same TVP for the insert query then it is not inserting the values to it.
I dont know what is happening & also error is also not coming.

**Here's my query :**

```
CREATE TYPE Mapping_n_Info_Master_Type AS TABLE
(
    quantity INT,
    product_id INT,
    sell_order_no VARCHAR(20),
    selling_product_id VARCHAR(20),
    tax_id INT
);
GO

CREATE PROC spInsert_Rs_Sell_Order_Master
(
    @tvp_Mapping_n_Info_Master Mapping_n_Info_Master_Type READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        --Start This Part is not Working
         INSERT INTO
            RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master 
         SELECT 
            sell_order_no,product_id,selling_product_id,tax_id,qty
         FROM
            @tvp_Mapping_n_Info_Master

        --End This Part is not Working


        --Insert Logic For Sell Order Mapping
        UPDATE 
            RS_Sell_Order_Mapping 
        SET
            quantity  = TVP.quantity    
        FROM 
            @tvp_Mapping_n_Info_Master tvp
            INNER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Mapping AS SOM ON
            TVP.product_id = SOM.product_id AND TVP.sell_order_no = SOM.sell_order_no
        WHERE 
            SOM.product_id = TVP.product_id
                AND
            SOM.sell_order_no = TVP.sell_order_no

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

         DECLARE @ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR(MAX), @SEVERITY INT, @STATE INT
         SELECT @SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @STATE = ERROR_STATE()
         ,@ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' err src line: ' + CAST( ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '');           
         --@ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
         ROLLBACK;
         -- RE-THROW EXCEPTION FOR DIAGNOSTIC VISIBILITY
         RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG ,@SEVERITY, @STATE);         
         RETURN

    END CATCH
END
```

My Table looks like this 
[image]

Do I want to change the sequence of parameter that I have supplied to the insert query.
Please give your suggestions to this

Comment: You have used **qty** instead of **quantity** in the insert query. I guess that may be the issue. In TVP you have defined quantity and in insert query you are using qty.

Comment: Thank you Krishnaraj For your help.....!!!!

Comment: Can you please tell me why we have to use this TAble type & what is table type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as:

```
INSERT INTO 
RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master (sell_order_no,
                              product_id,
                              selling_product_id,
                              tax_id,
                              qty) 
SELECT MIM.sell_order_no,
       MIM.product_id,
       MIM.selling_product_id,
       MIM.tax_id,
       MIM.quantity
FROM
@tvp_Mapping_n_Info_Master as MIM;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why we have to use this TAble type & what is table type